Gibbs phenomenon in sensor data
I’ve been thinking about the Gibbs phenomenon lately, and I wonder if it is more of a mathematical nuisance than a real life issue.
Gibbs describes the approximation error of a discontinuous function. However, if sample sensor data fast, gradients are always finite.
Thus, is Gibbs phenomenon even relevant for sensor data, or is it only relevant for purely synthetic/ digital signals?

True time-domain discontinuities require an infinitely long Fourier series to represent them. Typically there is an anti-aliasing low-pass filter that would be applied (I would imagine), which would mean the signal would not truly be presented as discontinuous to the sensor that’s sampling the signal.

It's certainly a real-life issue if someone designs a system with a "brick wall" filter where it shouldn't be.  Especially when you inherit responsibility for that system.

@TimWescott can you elaborate? I find your remark interesting. How does a brick-wall filter relate to Gibbs?

If you have edges in your sensor data, and you filter that data with a "brick wall" filter, then you will, essentially, be looking at a discontinuous function that's approximated by a finite-bandwidth signal.  You'll see ringing, and be able to call it "the Gibbs phenomenon".
